# Split array by subarrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array, e.g.

```
char[] myArr = {'a', 'b', '1', '2', 'c', 'd', '1', '2', 'e', 'f'}
```

in this case, the delimiting subsequence is {'1', '2'}.

I want to get the array split by this sequence and have in result a list of arrays:

```
{'a', 'b'}
{'c', 'd'}
{'e', 'f'}
```

What is the fastest way to do it?

Comment: should you add the #homework tag?

Comment: ... sounds like a school question to test your logic, not your syntax.

Comment: Nope, it's not a homework. I use this to parse sniffed data packages from byte[] array. I post this char[] question just as example and it seems that repliers don't understand me right. I need universal method for such parsing, not for parsing only char[] arrays.

Answer (score 2):

```
new string(myArr)
    .Split(new[] { "12" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Select(s => s.ToCharArray())
        .ToList();
```

Or, if you mean "array" when you say "list", then

```
new string(myArr)
    .Split(new[] { "12" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Select(s => s.ToCharArray())
        .ToArray();
```

Also, you might prefer `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`.

If this is homework, however, this solution is probably unacceptable.

---

As you ask about processing bytes, here's an adaptation for that purpose.  First, a couple of methods to convert a byte array to a string and back:

```
string ByteArrayToString(byte[] arr)
{
    char[] charArray = arr.Select(b => (char)b).ToArray();
    return new string(charArray);
}

byte[] StringToByteArray(string s)
{
    //this method maps each char in the string to a single output byte;
    //all chars should be in the range 0 to 255.  The checked 
    //conversion will catch any data that violates this requirement.

    return s.Select(c => checked ( (byte)c )).ToArray();
}
```

Now, the example code fragment:

```
byte[] myArr = Whatever();
byte[] myDelim = WhateverElse();

string sourceData = ByteArrayToString(myArr);
string delimiter = ByteArrayToString(myDelim);

string[] splitData = sourceData.Split(new [] { delimiter }, StringSplitOptions.None);
byte[][] result = splitData.Select(StringToByteArray);
```

Comment: Could you please give example of such parsing for byte[] array?

Comment: @Roman Hm, I am not sure why I never responded to your comment; sorry.  For byte arrays, this approach won't work, because the Split method is defined in the string class.  You could potentially convert the bytes to chars and then apply the method I describe, however; the edited answer shows one approach.  However, it's a bit hokey, since chars are not bytes.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by using a [ForEach loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) and the [Char.IsLetter function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyxz6h5w.aspx). Show us some code and we will help you.

Comment: I don't think the question as posed justifies the use of `char.IsLetter` -- the OP states that the sequences should be split by the subsequence `'1', '2'`, not that all non-letter characters should be considered as separators, nor that only letters are valid return data.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working with characters, you could convert your `myArr` array into a string, and use C#'s `String.Split` method. The result will be an array of strings, and you can split those up into individual characters when you are all done, here is an example:

```
  char[] myArr = {'a', 'b', '1', '2', 'c', 'd', '1', '2', 'e', 'f'};
  var myArrFlattened = "";
  myArr.ToList().ForEach(c => myArrFlattened += c.ToString());
  var separators = new string[] {"12"}; // put your sequences of characters here as a string
  myArrFlattened.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

The value of that last line is this array: `{"ab", "cd", "ef"}`, this code doesn't split the strings up into character lists, to do that, you could use `foreach` and apply the `String.ToCharArray` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = new String(myArr);
string[] parts = s.Split(new string[] {"12"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

You can then convert the results to char arrays with

```
var list = new List<char[]>();
foreach (string part in parts) {
    list.Add(part.ToCharArray());
}
```

---

EDIT: As you need a universal approach, here are two generic solutions.

If the length of the sub-arrays is always the same then you could do it like this:

```
public List<T[]> GetSubArrays<T>(T[] array)
{
    const int LengthOfSpearator = 2, LengthOfSubArray = 2;
    const int LengthOfPattern = LengthOfSpearator + LengthOfSubArray;

    var list = new List<T[]>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= array.Length - LengthOfSubArray; i += LengthOfPattern) {
        T[] subarray = new T[LengthOfSubArray];
        Array.Copy(array, i, subarray, 0, LengthOfSubArray);
        list.Add(subarray);
    }
    return list;
}
```

---

If the length of the sub-arrays is variable, then the algorithm becomes more complicated. We also have to constrain the generic parameter to be IEquatable in order to be able to make the comparison.

```
public List<T[]> GetSubArrays<T>(T[] array, T[] separator)
    where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    int maxSepIndex = array.Length - separator.Length;
    var list = new List<T[]>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= array.Length; ) {
        // Get index of next separator or array.Length if none is found
        int sepIndex;
        for (sepIndex = i; sepIndex <= maxSepIndex; sepIndex++) {
            int k;
            for (k = 0; k < separator.Length; k++) {
                if (!array[sepIndex + k].Equals(separator[k])) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (k == separator.Length) { // Separator found at sepIndex
                break;
            }
        }
        if (sepIndex > maxSepIndex) { // No separator found, subarray goes until end.
            sepIndex = array.Length;
        }

        int lenSubarray = sepIndex - i;
        T[] subarray = new T[lenSubarray];
        Array.Copy(array, i, subarray, 0, lenSubarray);
        list.Add(subarray);
        i = sepIndex + separator.Length;
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I need universal way to do this. ActuallyI have byte[] array. I just put this char[] as example.

Comment: Oh, so huge code. I know I can do it like that. I thought that there are some easier and faster way to make this because I need to parse thousands packages per minute.

Comment: If the delimiting sequence is relatively long, then the [Boyer–Moore algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) might speed up the search of the separator. However, it would make the algorithm even more complicated.